# how to loop a list without repeating the pair

Tags: python

I want to loop through a list to find a sum of pair equal to the variable "N". without repeating the pair

```
list=[0,1,2,3,4]
```

repeating pair

```
[0,1],[1,0],[2,3],[3,2]....etc
[0,0],[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]...etc
```

code

```
    num_list=[28,33,34,65,71]
    n=99
    pair=0
    count=0
    for i in range(len(num_list)-1):
        for j in range(len(num_list)):
            if i==j:
                pass
            else:
                pair=num_list[i] + num_list[j]
                if pair == n:
                    count+=1
    print(count)
```

expected output

```
2
```

my output

```
3
```

Comment: Do you mean number of pairs?

Comment: yes, number of  pair equal ot N

Comment: Got it, you can use a set to keep track of already seen pairs, check my answer below @pragathiswarj

Comment: You are re-implementing itertools.combinations, with a bug. Set j's start to i+1. Better - use itertools. Even better - there's an O(n) implementation using a set, if you research the "two sum" problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
from itertools import combinations
lst = [28,33,34,65,71]
n = 99
cnt = 0
for entry in combinations(lst,2):
  if sum(entry) == n:
    cnt +=1
print(cnt)
```

output

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check each number in the list with every number after it in the list. You can do this by slicing the first list.

The first loop you slice all but the last number. You do not need it since you will be checking it against all other numbers.

The second loop you slice all numbers from the current number to the end of the list and check those numbers. You wont have any single number checked against itself unless it occurs twice in the list

```py
num_list=[28,33,34,65,71]
n=99
count=0
for index, num1 in enumerate(num_list[:-1]):
    for num2 in num_list[index:]:
        if num1+num2 == n:
            count += 1
print(count)
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: creating these slices will be memory intensive, and unnecessary. The same can be achieved by setting's the start index for j to i+1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with the existing loop structure, you can add a list to keep track of `num_list[i]` values that have already been counted as a pair. Then, in each iteration, check if your `num_list[j]` value is in that list. If it is, then you know that this pair has already been counted in the opposite order.

```
     num_list=[28,33,34,65,71]
    prev_i = [] #this will keep track of i's that have been in a counted pair
    n=99
    pair=0
    count=0
    for i in range(len(num_list)-1):
        for j in range(len(num_list)):
            if i==j:
                pass
            else:
                pair=num_list[i] + num_list[j]
                #Check if pair are the same or already counted
                if pair == n and (not num_list[j] in prev_i):
                    prev_i.append(num_list[i]) #add i to the prev_i list
                    count+=1
    print(count)
```